# AWK not print columns when converting row to columns on AIX

Tags: awk, aix

I am working on converting rows to columns on AIX for the below file

```
cat test.txt
SUV
BMW X5
CADILLAC ESCALDE
Honda CRV
Toyota RAV

Sedan
Lexus is250
Acura
Suburu
```

Converting rows to columns

```
cat test.txt |awk -v RS="" '{$1=$1}1'
SUV
BMW X5
CADILLAC ESCALDE
Honda CRV
Toyota RAV
Sedan
Lexus is250
Acura
Suburu
```

But

```
cat test.txt | awk -v RS="" '{print $1, $2, $3, $4, $5}'
SUV BMW X5 CADILLAC ESCALDE 
Sedan Lexus is250 Acura
```

So, how can I print all the columns as following without specifying them

```
SUV BMW X5 CADILLAC ESCALDE Honda CRV Toyota RAV
Sedan Lexus is250 Acura Suburu
```

Thanks

Comment: If the awk you are using is behaving as you describe given that input file then that awk is severely broken. Get a new one, preferably gawk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not able to verify this on AIX but give this a try

```
 awk -F'\n' -v RS= '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) printf "%s",$i OFS; print ""}'
```

in your script default field separator is used that's why you don't see the full record from `$1..$5`

If you know that you have 5 fields

```
awk -F'\n' -v RS= '{print $1,$2,$3,$4,$5}'
```

should work too.

Comment: Y NO 'awk to the rescue!'?

Comment: It doesn't matter if it works or not - his awk is apparently broken so he shouldn't be using it (who knows what else is broken in it?) and when he gets a working awk he won't need a workaround.

Answer (score 1):

An alternate one-liner:

```
awk -F'\n' -v RS='' '{$1=$1};1' test.txt
```

The `$1=$1` syntax forces awk to recalculate `$0`, which converts the Field Separator from '\n' to ' ' (the default OFS).

Comment: this may not be working on AIX.  Also semicolon is redundant.

Comment: @karakfa I normally don't use the semicolon.  However, someone on SO once said it is required.  For example, gawk's man says: "Multiple  statements  may  be  put on one line by separating them with a ";".  This applies to both the statements within the action part of a pattern-action pair (the usual case), and to the pattern-action statements themselves."  Even though it says that, it works without it.

Comment: correct but `1` is not a statement, it's the condition which implies the default statement `{print}`.

Comment: I'm referring to: "...and to the pattern-action statements themselves."...  Meaning pattern-action pairs on one line require semicolons between them.

Comment: Since that requirement to separate statements with `;`s wasn't part of the original awk language and no awk interpreter has ever enforced it since someone decided to introduce it, if any awk interpreter ever enforced it then that interpreter would quickly be discarded again in favor of one that doesn't so that the gazillion awk scripts written without that pointless construct would continue to function. So, ignore that requirement - it is useless and not backward-compatible and therefore is not now and never will be implemented.